# Interface typing array with multiple possible object types

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an interface that contains a property which is an array containing 2 different possible object types:

```
<Type>FormerComponent and FormerGenericComponent
```

Here are my interfaces

```
interface FormerConfigColumn {
    container: ViewContainerRef
    components?: Type<FormerComponent>[]|FormerGenericComponent[];
}

interface FormerGenericComponent {
    component: Type<FormerComponent>;
}
```

The above doesn't work the way I would like it to. I think the above defines an array containing only `Type<FormerComponent>`s or only `FormerGenericComponent`s

I want FormerConfigColumn.components to contain an array of objects, and said objects can **either** be `Type<FormerComponent>` **or** `FormerGenericComponent`.

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: can you simplify your question with simple Interfaces, I have no clue what `Type` and `FormerComponent` is

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
interface FormerConfigColumn {
    container: ViewContainerRef
    components?: (FormerComponent | FormerGenericComponent)[];
}
```

This will define `components` as an optional property of `FormerConfigColumn` that holds an array which can be filled with `FormerComponent` or `FormerGenericComponent`.

If you want `components` to hold an array of `FormerComponent` or `FormerGenericComponent`, but not both at the same time, then use:

```
    components?: (FormerComponent[] | FormerGenericComponent[]);
```